# LD_LIBRARY_PATH: Undefined variable error

Tags: matlab, csh, ubuntu-14.04, setenv

I am trying matlab script that depends on MCR. I have wrapper script that sets up environment variables for this MCR directory before executing the actual programme. The wrapper is as follows.

```
#!/bin/csh

set thisdir = `pwd`

# --- SET UP ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES ---
echo --- setting up environment variables ---
# presumed location of MATLAB Component Runtime (MCR) v7.14
# if the MCR is in a different location, edit the line below
set mcr_root = /home/foo/MATLAB_Component_Runtime
echo $mcr_root
setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH $mcr_root/v81/runtime/glnxa64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH $mcr_root/v81/sys/os/glnxa64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH $mcr_root/v81/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64/native_threads:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH $mcr_root/v81/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64/server:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH $mcr_root/v81/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
setenv XAPPLRESDIR $mcr_root/v81/X11/app-defaults
# (these may be set permanently by copying the above lines into your login script)
```

now when I run this script `./run_script` I get this error -

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH: Undefined variable.
```

I googled a lot and found some questions related, but none was usefull enough.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's probably the case that `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` doesn't exist before you run your script. The first line in your script that sets `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` tries to append the existing path -- but the variable has not been defined.

If you change the line in your script to

```
setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH $mcr_root/v81/runtime/glnxa64
```

then it will work as you expect.